# Installing Ghostscript with Imagick on Azure php server

Tags: php, azure, imagemagick, ghostscript

I've run into a bit of trouble with PHP converting PDF files to images using Imagick (in PHP). When i try to do so i get a error 500. I tried troubleshooting with my host provider however they got no error, and couldn't change the version because i was using a shared server. Then i got the idea to use Azure for this, and after a long while i managed to install Imagick on the server, however i found out it apparantly needs Ghostscript to work with PDF files.

So my question is, how do i install Ghostscript on Azure servers, or alternatively, is it possible to build Imagemagick with Ghostscript for windows?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Azure servers" - are you talking about Virtual Machines? Cloud Services (web/worker roles)? Web Apps? You also stated you "managed to install Imagick on the server" - again, it's unclear what you did, and what you're working with.

Comment: I apologize, i am using a web app, on Azure Servers, running PHP 5.6. i have via ftp managed to install Imagemagick along with Imagick, however i cannot get it to recognize Ghostscript

Answer (score 0):

You can follow https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/12/07/php-imagemagick-on-azure-web-apps/ to install ImageMagick extension on Azure Web Apps. And then download the ghostscript installer for windows from http://ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html. Install it on your local PC, then copy the application folder like `C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.19` to the Azure site the same as the above step like to `d:\home\site\gs`.

Modify the `applicationHost.xdt` file, add the `gs` path to the **PATH** variable. E.G. `<add name="Path" value="%Path%d:\home\site\imagick\;d:\home\site\gs9.19\bin\;" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />`.

Then you can leverage `exec()` function in your PHP script to invoke ghostscript cli command. Like `echo exec("gswin32c.exe -h");`

Comment: i've done all the steps except the path, i had them on 2 seperate lines which crashed the server, however this didn't. unfortunately when i use it with the existing php that leverages Imagick (and as i understand it, this uses ghostscript) i get a 500 error (internal server error) i was thinking this was because it couldn't find ghostscript, but perhaps there is something else wrong, as when i ran the php script i get "Please report bugs to bugs.ghostscript.com."

Comment: If you run command `gswin32c.exe -h` in cmdlet, you can find the last line of the output is *Please report bugs to bugs.ghostscript.com.*. So maybe there are some other errors in your scripts. you can enable display errors for troubleshooting. Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` in the top of your scripts, and find the issue.

Comment: thank you for your input, however gswin32c.exe -h gives me the same output as gswin32c.exe -? . however i will try to have a look at the code to display errors, however i don't know if they will ever reach me with a 500 server error.

Comment: the command param `-?` is the same with `-h`, and as `shell_exec` returns all of the output stream as a string. `exec` returns the last line of the output by default, but can provide all output as an array specifed as the second parameter. So you can use `echo shell_exec("gswin32c.exe -?");` for looking all the output.